# New IIS 10 site on different port can only be accessible on VM directly via http://localhost:portnumber

Tags: iis

I am managing a Windows Server 2016 Azure VM in the cloud that has IIS version 10 installed.

It currently has 2 sites that is live

Namely

`http://www.clientdomain.com`

`http://portal.clientdomain.com`

Both these sites work.

I need to setup a test site just for testing purposes.

I create 2 test sites in IIS and setup the bindings with hostname `portal.clientdomain.com` on port 88 and port 89 respectively in the IIS bindings.

*I use a different port than 80,443 so it doesn't interfere with the live site*

This works if I type in my browser
`http://localhost:88` or `https://localhost:89` on the VM directly

However, it needs to be accessible outside the VM on the internet.

For one or other reason I can't get the site url to open up in the browser.

Some of the URLs I have tried:

- `http://portal.clientdomain.com`
- `http://sitename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:88`
- `http://TheIPAdress:88`
- `http://clientdomain.com:88`

which all the following cause the browser to gives the error `This site cannot be reached` with details `The server took too long to respond`

I tried various bindings too but nothing works.

My question:

Why does `http://localhost:88`,`https://localhost:89`,`http://portal.clientdomain.com` work directly on the server, however `http://portal.clientdomain.com:88` or `http://portal.clientdomain.com:89` do not if I made the bindings match. I also tried it with no bindings. Nothing works.

I have tried adding the ports to the Firewall as Inbound TCP rules but result is the same.

Comment: There are two levels of firewalls for Windows VM on Azure (Windows Firewall on Windows itself, and Azure's networking rules). You have to configure both if you use non-standard ports. You also need to learn how people describe IIS site bindings https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background as the information you provided above is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. Adding an inbound rule to Azure as well resolved it